# How to show dropdown menu in modal above red div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with dropdown menu which is inside of a bootstrap modal. And I have another red div-box. I need that opened dropdown menu to be above this red box. Z-index not working...

Here is me [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jrdo0rw/) and css.

```
.box1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10000;
  left: 280px;
  top: 200px;
}
#menu1 {
  z-index: 100001;
}
```

EDITED: modal above redbox and redboxe above dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the z-index of #myModal not the drop-down menu. Because the parent element of drop-down is modal. The reason for this is z-index is always inherited from the parent (if it is set). So default from bootstrap there is z-index value for modal(the parent of drop-down).

```
.box1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10000;
  left: 280px;
  top: 200px;
}
#myModal {
  z-index: 10001;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: no, I need red box above modal but dropdown menu before red box

Comment: You cant do that. As in the answer z-index is always inherited from the parent. Only way you can achieve this is by putting red div inside the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `z-index: 10000` from box1 to `z-index: 999` like this:

```
.box1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 280px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: no, I need red box above modal but dropdown menu before red box

Comment: u mean dropdown menu inside the modal need to be above the red box. right ?